# TFTP is not recognized as an internal or external command

Tags: visual-studio-2013, tfs, tfs-power-tools

I am trying to Move shelvset from one branch to other in TFS.
I am doing this as per the procedure given in article  http://benjii.me/2014/04/move-shelveset-to-different-branch-in-tfs/

When I gave the command TFTP, it's giving below error,
 "TFTP is not recognized as an internal or external command."

Answer (score 3):

You need to install the TFS power tools, and then run that command from the proper dir that contains the tfpt.exe that gets installed with the Power Tools.

Comment: e.g. "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Team Foundation Server 2015 Power Tools" for VS15/TFSPT15